# React Router protected route wrapper does not detect the new authentication state from AuthProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here it's shown the most basic implementation of authentication in React-Router v6. `loggedIn` flag in `PrivateRoutes` does not change when updated to true after updating context, and so the private routes cannot be accessed when navigating to them. Why is that?

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useNavigate
} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AuthProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />

            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/secret" element={<SecretPage />} />
              {/** ... Other protected pages ...*/}
            </Route>
            
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

function PrivateRoutes() {
  const { loggedIn } = useAuth();

  return loggedIn ? <Outlet />: <Navigate to="/" />
}

function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <button onClick={() => navigate('/secret')}>
      Go to secret page
    </button>
  </>
}

function SecretPage() {
  return <>
    <h1>Secret Page</h1>
  </>
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { loggedIn, signIn } = useAuth()

  return
    <AuthContext.Provider value={loggedIn}>
      
      {/** 
       * Button to trigger sign in and showing the
       * current status.
      */}
      <button onClick={signIn}>LogIn</button>
      <h2>Logged In: {loggedIn.toString()}</h2>
      <p>-----------------------</p>

      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}

const useAuth = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

  const signIn = () => {

    {/** sign in logic ....*/}

    setLoggedIn(true);
  };

  return { loggedIn, signIn };
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useAuth` is a React hook and React hooks don't share internal state. Each instance of `useAuth` has its own independent `loggedIn` state.

Refactor the `AuthProvider` to hold the `loggedIn` state and update the `useAuth` hook to consume the provided context value. This is how all instances of `useAuth` get the same value.

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState();

  const signIn = () => {
    {/** sign in logic ....*/}
    setLoggedIn(true);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ loggedIn, signIn }}>
      {/** 
       * Button to trigger sign in and showing the
       * current status.
      */}
      <button onClick={signIn}>LogIn</button>
      <h2>Logged In: {loggedIn.toString()}</h2>
      <p>-----------------------</p>

      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);
```

```js
function PrivateRoutes() {
  const { loggedIn } = useAuth();

  if (loggedIn === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return loggedIn
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
function PrivateRoutes(){
  const {loggedIn} = useAuth();
  return loggedIn ? <Outlet/>: <Navigate to="/" state={{from:location}} replace/>

}
```